# Why is my fixed div appearing below the content in IE8?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, position, fixed

I am having a weird problem in IE8 when trying to get a fixed div on top of my screen that hides all other content for a moment.

What actually happens now is that the fixed div appears right **below** my content. Code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body>
      <table width="50%">...</table>
      <div class="cadre2" style="width: 50%">...</div>

      <div style="z-index: 9999; position: fixed; background-color: #ff0000; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">This should be on top!</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

But the result in Internet Explorer 8 is something like this:

```
____________________
|                  |
|                  |
|     CONTENT      |
|                  |
|__________________|
|                  |
| THIS SHOULD BE   |
|       ON         |
|      TOP!        |
|                  |
|__________________|
```

Not surprisingly this works absolutely fine in FireFox.

Does anyone have any idea what can be causing this to go wrong in IE8? Can it be any CSS attribute set to any of the preceding HTML? Although I highly doubt this since the fixed div is not nested in any other element apart from the body.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you specified a doctype?

Comment: Works fine for me in both- http://jsfiddle.net/Txdv7/

Comment: @Cdeez Yes it works fine in jsfiddle. This is the issue. It works for me too when I just create a simple testpage with this code. But it doesn't work in the page I actually need it for. So it must be due to some minor thing I can't find.

Comment: @Kayo Yes, the doctype is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

Comment: May be styles are overridden? If thats written as inline style then there shouldn't be an overriding issue. Is it?

Comment: @Cdeez Yes I have written it as inline style on purpose to avoid it from being overridden.

Comment: There may be something with the table and cadre2 class div. Can you post the css of them?

Comment: Change the doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` and try again. Fixed it for me in IE7

Comment: @rjokelai Indeed, this fixes the issue. I changed it to `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` and it was solved. I'm not sure how this will impact all pages though... Thanks for your post. Feel free to write it as an answer and I'll accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the doctype definition to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

You can find some explanation at http://webdesign.about.com/cs/doctype/a/aaquirksmode.htm